# high charts line graph x-axis issue

Tags: highcharts

I am using high charts to plot graphs in my project.I am plotting line graph.If data is huge then i face problem in visualizing the x axis.High charts plot the x axis values side by side.They get overlapped .What is the option provided to plot them slant so that they don't overlapped.

Comment: got the answer i used labels: { rotation: angle} and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For X-axis, you can provide label rotation value

```
 xAxis: {
                     categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                     labels: {
                        rotation: -45,
                        align: 'right',
                        style: {
                            font: 'normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                     }

                  },
```